# Post request to ASP API from Angular 6

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, cors, http-headers

Using Angular 6 for front end and Aps Web Api as backend

I have prepared simple CRUD operation in ASP which works fine in Postman.
|*> To use in Postman

```
=> Select "Body" Tab
=> Select "raw" Radio Button 
=> Select "JSON (application/json)" from Dropdown
```

But giving below error while trying to Post with angular

> zone.js:2969 OPTIONS "http://localhost:8008/api/user" 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>   localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at '"http://localhost:8008/api/user"' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I have tried Enabling CORS pluggin with Chrome Browser

Try 1 :

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');

let userData = 
{
      "name":"Suji",
      "email":"suji@yahoo.com",
      "mobile":"9864224"
}
this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8008/api/user",userData,{headers})
```

Try 2 :

```
const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })}; 

let userData = 
{
      "name":"Suji",
      "email":"suji@yahoo.com",
      "mobile":"9864224"
}
this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8008/api/user",userData,httpOptions);
```

Try 3 : Trying with stringyfy

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');

let userData = 
{
      "name":"Suji",
      "email":"suji@yahoo.com",
      "mobile":"9864224"
}
this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8008/api/user",JSON.stringify(userData),{headers})
```

Try 4 : Trying with stringyfy

```
const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })}; 

let userData = 
{
      "name":"Suji",
      "email":"suji@yahoo.com",
      "mobile":"9864224"
}
this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8008/api/user",JSON.stringify(userData),httpOptions);
```

Let me know where I am missing or what else need to be set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the CORS issue because the API and angular app are running on a different port.

You need to create a proxy for fixing this issue:

1. Create `proxy.conf.json` in your project directory.

   ```
                 {  
                     "/api/*": {  
                       "target": "http://localhost:8008",  
                       "secure": false,  
                       "logLevel": "debug"  
                  }  
               }
   ```
2. Add ProxyConfig key in `Angular.json` file:

   ```
               "serve": {  
               "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",  
               "options": {  
                   "browserTarget": "YourApp:build",  
                   "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"  
               },
   ```
3. Change `package.json`:

   ```
           "scripts": {  
              "ng": "ng",  
               "start": "ng serve --port 4200 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",  
               "build": "ng build",  
               "test": "ng test",  
               "lint": "ng lint",  
               "e2e": "ng e2e"  
           },
   ```
4. Now Change your service to use relative path for the service url:

   `this.httpClient.post("/api/user",userData,httpOptions);`

Now, all the setup is done for making a proxy request. Now, when you run the Application using npm start:

It runs `ng serve --port 4200 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` command.

Angular App runs on port 4200 and calls the `proxy.conf.json` so any API request having `api/*` takes the target from `proxy.conf.json`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution really helped a lot and working.

Comment: @SujayUN, Glad to hear that!

Comment: What if my api runs on a different ip address and on another port?
Would that still be possible?
I am using this, but it is not working:
{
  "/event": {
    "target": "http://my.ip.address:8081",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}